# Hangman in C. Questions regarding arrays and strings

Tags: c

Ok so this is my code. I'm supposed to make a program that asks from one player a word and requests from the other one to find it, guessing one letter at a time. So basically, Hangman. My questions are these:

The `SCounter` variable increases to random numbers when I try to increase it by one. I've tried thinking about it and I don't know why. For example, when the guess word is `Kala`(Greek for "Good/Fine"), SCounter equals to wrong amount of letters when I type guess any letter after the first.

My second question is in regards to `guess`. My program only works when I write `char guess[2]`. When I write `char guess[0]` it loops forever. I don't underestand why.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

SetConsoleOutputCP(1253);

int i = 0;
start :printf("Enter the guess word: ");
char word[25], sword[25];
char guess[2];
char alphabet[28] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "};
int Counter = 6;
int SCounter = 0; 
gets(word);
for (i=0; i<strlen(word); i++){
    sword[i]='-';
}
while(Counter != 0)
{
    printf("So far: ");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(alphabet); i++)
    {
        printf("%c", alphabet[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Guess a character: ");
    gets(guess);
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
            if(word[i] == guess[0])
            {
                sword[i] = guess[0];
            }
            /*else
            {
                Counter--;
                printf("You only have %d wrong guesses left.\n", Counter);
            }*/
    }
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(sword); i++)
    {
        if (word[i]==sword[i]){
            SCounter++;
        }
        printf("%c", sword[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d letters found so far.", SCounter);
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(alphabet); i++)
    {   
        if  (strlen(guess)<2)
        {
        if(alphabet[i] == guess[0])
            {
            alphabet[i] = '-';
            }
        }
    }
    if (SCounter == strlen(word)){
        Counter = 0;
    }
    if (strcmp(word, sword)==0){
        printf("Congratulation Player 1! You win!\n");
        goto start;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: char guess[0] declare a zero-length string. That doesn't seem very useful. You say "_The SCounter variable goes when I try to increase it by one_"... what does 'the variable goes' actually mean?

Comment: I actually forgot to properly end the phrasing lol. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `SCounter` variable is not reset to zero between iterations, so it keeps growing.

Move the declaration / initialization of `SCounter` to the scope where it is used to fix this problem:

```
int SCounter = 0; // This is where the declaration should be
// Remove the declaration of SCounter at the outermost scope.
for(i = 0; i < strlen(sword); i++)
{
    if (word[i]==sword[i]){
        SCounter++;
    }
    printf("%c", sword[i]);
}
```

Here are a few notes on the rest of your program:

- Using `goto` is not going to score extra points with your instructor. To many, this is a red flag; consider rewriting without `goto`.
- The `gets` function is inherently unsafe. Please refrain from using it for new development. Use `fgets(guess, 2, stdin);` instead.

Comment: Wow I'm stupid. I actually moved around a lot of my declarations in order to make everything else work and I completely forgot about that one. The program works now. If I wanted to write it without `goto` then I assume that I'll just move the declarations inside the first `while` loop. All but Counter one right?

Comment: I just noticed that the program does not work if the secret word is only one letter.

Comment: @user3601507 You would need an extra `while` loop there (I'd prefer a `do`/`while` actually, because you want to run at least once, and that is what the `do`/`while` loop is best for.